# SQL: Check rows for same entries in specific columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need a select command to do the following:

I have a table like this

```
ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | colN | ...
23 | asf  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
23 | asf  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
59 | asf  |  567 | rrr  | ...  | ...
59 | asf  |  gh1 | rrr  | ...  | ...
02 | la1  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
02 | la1  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
```

There are always 2 rows with the same ID. Now I want to select this ones, which have also the same entries in some specific other columns (here col1, col2, col3), but not necessarily in other columns.

As a result for the example I want to have this

```
23 | asf  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
23 | asf  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
02 | la1  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
02 | la1  |  slf | rrr  | ...  | ...
```

Comment: You need a PRIMARY KEY. This is a rule of relational data.

Comment: Thank you. But acutally i dont know what it is. I am a sql beginner. It seems that I have to learn more basics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theses tables do have a primary key which is unique amongst all tuples? In that case you can do a simple self join:

```
SELECT e1.* FROM entities e1 
  INNER JOIN entities e2 ON 
    e1.pkey != e2.pkey
    AND e1.ID = e2.ID
    AND e1.col1 = e2.col1
    AND e1.col2 = e2.col2
    AND e1.col3 = e2.col3;
```

Another option would be aggregation:

```
SELECT * FROM entities WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM entities GROUP BY ID, col1, col2, col3
    HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: The OP's results show duplicate ID's that need to be taken into consideration. Probably just need a groupby

Comment: No. Unfortunately, there is no primary key or something unique. Your second solutions doesnt seem to work. I tried it.

Comment: It should work, at least I don't see the mistake.

Comment: Yes it works. I did something wrong. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

> select * from test where id in
>
> (select a.id from test a
>
> inner join test b
>
> on (a.id, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3)=(b.id, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3)
>
> group by (a.id)
>
> having count(`*`)>(select count(`*`) from test c
>
> where c.id=a.id))

**[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e97a/32/0)**